# Can't retrieve data from firebase reatime database in recyclerview. Kotlin android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

[image: This is my database stucture.]

I am making a chatting applicatio. and want to show all people in recycler view of an activity, but I can't get people information from app.

I had made a node named "USER" in this I had made a list of node named "${uid of USER}" and in every uid node there is a node named "Profile" node and in this node user's details are present like name uid and email and I want to retrive the details from every "Profile" node which is present in "${uid of USER} nodes which is present in "USER" node. in previous I had stored only in ${uid of USER} directly without making any profile node. this is working fine(there was a different code for it).

```
db.child("User")
    .addValueEventListener(object :ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            for (i in snapshot.children)

                db.child(USER).child(i.key.toString()).child("Profile")
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
                        override fun onDataChange(data: DataSnapshot) {

                            val user = data.getValue(User::class.java)

                            userList.add(user!!)

                        }

                        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                            
                        }
                    })
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        }
    })
```

If you can than please provide a code for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have an adapter somewhere that shows the items in `userList` in a list/recycler view. In that case, you need to tell the adapter that you've updated the list - otherwise it won't refresh the UI. You can do this by [calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()) after the loop that adds the children to the list.

Though they're not causing the above problem, there are two other things you'll want to change in the code:

1. Stop ignoring errors and implement `onCancelled`.
2. When you load a certain path in the database, all data under that path is already included in the snapshot you get. So there's no need for the nested load call.

With those changes:

```
db.child("User")
    .addValueEventListener(object :ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (child in snapshot.children)
                data = child.child("Profile") // 
                val user = data.getValue(User::class.java)
                userList.add(user!!)
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // 
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
             Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", error.toException()) // 
        }
    })
```

You'll need to modify the `adapter` variable in this code to point to *your* adapter.

Comment: Thanks again for helping but my previous question did not solved in which I had asked how to change value in database whenever app stop() not destroy() because destroy() working fine and thanks again

Comment: Kindly, Ok ok I am new to stackoverflow so I had forgot to accept the answer but can't vote because I have only 7 reputation so I accepted your answer but can't vote. I think you understand my problem.